# Python3 submodules setup does not update paths when run with -m switch

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, path

I have the following project structure:

```
server/
   server.py
   __init__.py

   sockets/
      module.py
      __init__.py
```

I set `PYTHONPATH` to one directory above server (for example `/home/user/server` contains server, `PYTHONPATH` is set `/home/user`).

The main file is `server.py`; it imports modules:

```
import sockets
from sockets.module import Module
```

When I run `python3 $PYTHONPATH/server/server.py` directly it works perfectly.
However when I call `python3 -m server.server.py` it fails, despite the fact that it is explicitly recommended to avoid Python path hell, but it fails to find the the module, with an ugly message:

```
/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding spec for 'server.server.py' (<class 'ImportError'>: No module named 'sockets')
```

Why does the module import fail to import submodules?
How to properly setup sub-packages?

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour is entirely correct; `sockets` is not a *top-level module*. However, when you use `$PYTHONPATH/server/server.py`, Python also adds `$PYTHONPATH/server/` to the Python search path, so now `sockets` *is* a top-level module. You should never directly run files in a package.

Import `sockets` relative to the current package:

```
from . import sockets
from .sockets.module import Module
```

or use fully-qualified imports:

```
from server import sockets
from server.sockets.module import Module
```

Also see the [*Interface Options* section](https://docs.python.org/3//using/cmdline.html#interface-options) of the Python Setup and Usage section in the fine manual:

> If the script name refers directly to a Python file, the **directory containing that file is added to the start of `sys.path`**, and the file is executed as the `__main__` module.

Note that the `-m` switch takes a *python identifier*, not a filename, so use:

```
python -m server.server
```

leaving of the `.py` extension.

Comment: Thanks as I thought I missed something simple, though I believed for some reason that it includes it with -m import.

Comment: @IBr: when using `python -m` the current working directory is also added to the path, so you can change directories to `$PYTHONPATH` and then use `python -m server.server` and `$PYTHONPATH` will be added to your path automatically.