# Python run file from command line

Tags: python, centos

Yesterday I installed Python (with Numpy & Scipy) on CentOS, everthing works fine when I'm using the CLI and do some math. But now I try to execute a file, and then a weird error appears, searched all over the place but can't find the solution to fix this.

I'm running two Python versions, the version I'm using is 3.4, and I installed it at: /usr/local/bin

Then I made a file called test.py in the same directory, with this code:

```
import numpy
```

When I try to run it with:

```
./python3.4 -m test.py
```

I get this error:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.4: Error while finding spec for 'test.py' (<class 'AttributeError'>: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__')
```

I hope somebody can lead me into the right direction, thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `./python3.4 -m test` work? Does the rest of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27169803/258523) help any?

Comment: Alternatively, does `./python3.4 test.py` work?

Comment: Hehe ty, feeling really stupid right now. I thought the -m flag was required, I saw it  at http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/install.html. But this flag was the thing that caused the error. Now I can run .py files and I finally have a Cherrypy webserver up and running. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Running things like

```
 python -m <something>
```

invokes Python, which then tries to import a Python Module.

From your short example it doesn't appear to be a valid Python module

Try running with `python <your python code file>` instead.