# Python imports with __init__.py

Tags: python, terminal, python-import, directory-structure, pytest

No matter how I structure the imports in the code files and in the `__init__.py` files, I can't seem to get it right for executing the program *and* running the tests using `pytest`. How do I need to write the imports when my project structure looks like this:

```
src/
    __init__.py
    VocableFileWriter.py
    WordListHelper.py
    WordListReader.py
    XLDAttributeValueAdder.py

    exceptions/
        __init__.py
        XMLInvalidException.py
        XMLParseException.py

    gui/
        __init__.py
        GTKSignal.py
        XLDAttributeValueAdderWindow.py

    test/
        __init__.py
        test_XLDAttributeValueAdder.py

    xmlparser/
        __init__.py
        XMLParser.py
```

Currently I have them like this:

In the `__init__.py` files I have the imports like this (`src/__init__.py`):

```
from src import *
from src.exceptions import *
from src.xmlparser import *
```

and in a subpackage (`src/xmlparser/__init__.py`):

```
from src.xmlparser import *
```

So I guess those are project-absolute paths to the modules.
In the code files themselves I import like this:

```
import os
import sys
from VocableFileWriter import VocableFileWriter
from XLDAttributeValueAdder import XLDAttributeValueAdder
```

However, when I execute the code from the directory above `src` using:

```
./src/main.py
```

It tells me that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./src/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from VocableFileWriter import VocableFileWriter
File "/home/xiaolong/Development/PycharmProjects/xld-attribute-value-adder/src/VocableFileWriter.py", line 2, in <module>
    from XMLInvalidException import XMLInvalidException
ImportError: No module named 'XMLInvalidException'
```

It used to be a PyCharm project, but I couldn't get it to run with the imports structure PyCharm used when not using PyCharm but running it from the terminal, so I decided I wanted to take the whole import stuff into my own hands. So don't get confused by it being in a PyCharm directory.

I also want to be able to execute the tests using for example:

```
py.test src/test/test_XLDAttributeValueAdder.py
```

How do I solve this mess?

**Edit#1:**
I had the program running once, but then the test complained about missing modules, probably because it's in another subdirectory and I tried so many configurations, that I don't know how I had the program running anymore. If possible please add some explanation why a certain structure is correct and works for both, tests and the program itself.

**EDIT#2:**
I've managed to get the tests running now, but now the program doesn't run anymore.
I emptied all the `__init__.py` files and used only project-absolute paths in the code files like this (`src/test/test_XLDAttributeValueAdder.py`):

```
from src.VocableFileWriter import VocableFileWriter
from src.WordListHelper import WordListHelper
from src.WordListReader import WordListReader
from src.XLDAttributeValueAdder import XLDAttributeValueAdder
from src.exceptions.XMLInvalidException import XMLInvalidException
from src.exceptions.XMLParseException import XMLParserException
from src.xmlparser.XMLParser import XMLParser
from src.test.path_helper import go_up
from src.test.path_helper import go_in
```

and in the `main.py`:

```
from src.VocableFileWriter import VocableFileWriter
from src.XLDAttributeValueAdder import XLDAttributeValueAdder
```

the output of `./src/main.py`:

```
./src/main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./src/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from src.VocableFileWriter import VocableFileWriter
ImportError: No module named 'src'
```

**EDIT#3:**
I've tried the relative import way like this:

- `main.py` moved one directory up

The structure now looks like this:

```
main.py

src/
    __init__.py
    VocableFileWriter.py
    WordListHelper.py
    WordListReader.py
    XLDAttributeValueAdder.py

    exceptions/
        __init__.py
        XMLInvalidException.py
        XMLParseException.py

    gui/
        __init__.py
        GTKSignal.py
        XLDAttributeValueAdderWindow.py

    test/
        __init__.py
        test_XLDAttributeValueAdder.py

    xmlparser/
        __init__.py
        XMLParser.py
```

- `__init__.py` files empty
- `main.py` file gets relative

Imports look like this:

```
import os
import sys
from .src.VocableFileWriter import VocableFileWriter
from .src.XLDAttributeValueAdder import XLDAttributeValueAdder
```

When I try to run the `main.py` file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .src.VocableFileWriter import VocableFileWriter
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

However, there is a `__init__.py` file in the same directory as the `main.py` file, also empty.

Comment: The *main.py* file should not use relative imports, when you intent to call it directly. You moved it outside of the package structure, so that it's an independent module and suitable to use absolute imports for the package. I'll clearify my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use relative imports.

When doing `from src import *` in *src/__init__.py* you'll only import anything you've defined before calling the import. Most likely that's just nothing. If you've defined the `__all__` variable, you'll get the submodule from it, but maybe also an `AttributeError` if a variable hasn't been defined yet.

So instead import the modules you need explicitly where you need them like

```
from .VocableFileWriter import VocableFileWriter
from .exceptions.XMLInvalidException import XMLInvalidException
```

or lets say within *src/gui/GTKSignal.py*

```
from ..exceptions.XMLInvalidException import XMLInvalidException
```

Also you could use project-absolute paths like mentioned in your **Edit#2**.

---

Furthermore you've a problem with your path when calling `./src/main.py`. In this case the directory containing `src` is not in the path. Instead `./src/` is in the path. Therefore python doesn't consider it a package anymore and since there's no other package with that name available, the import fails.

Instead put your `main.py` module in the same directory like the `src` package or call it as a module with `python -m src.main`. Doing so you could also rename it to *src/**main**.py* and call the package instad with `python -m src`.

---

When using the first approach, `main` should use an absolute import structure. Just think of it as a module you put anywhere on your computer, while your `src` package is somewhere else, where it can be found by Python, like any other module or package installed by the system. It's not different, when it's located besides the package itself, since the current directory is in `sys.path`.

*main.py*

```
import os
import sys
from src.VocableFileWriter import VocableFileWriter
from src.XLDAttributeValueAdder import XLDAttributeValueAdder
```

Comment: The project absolute thing doesn't always work. For example for the tests it doesn't work. I guess it is because they're in another directory, or the directory from which pytest executes is different than the top level of my project, which I am in when executing the program. I'll test relative imports.

Comment: I've tried to use relative imports when the main.py is not outside of the src folder, but that also results in an error. Putting the main.py file outside of the src dir seems strange, since it's part of my program and is actually a source code file. If possible, I'd like it to stay inside the src folder. Here is the error I get, using relative imports, the main.py file being inside the src dir: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "./src/main.py", line 6, in <module> from .VocableFileWriter import VocableFileWriter SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`

Comment: @Zelphir You have to call it with `python -m src.main` then. If you call it with `./src/main.py`, it's treated as a standalone module, not a submodule of your src package.

Comment: Now I just get another error: `Error while finding spec for 'src.main.py' (<class 'AttributeError'>: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__')` This is crazy, why is it so complicated to get the program running *and* the pytest tests. In another project I used the python unittest framework and it worked fine, because the discovery or something works differently. It almost seems like pytest is incompatible with running programs, because of import issues. Idk what values I should set in a `__path__` variable either. Doing that seems like doing some weird unnecessary magic.

Comment: @Zelphir Your complete setup seems to be a little off. If you'd like to have a main in you package, consider using a [*_\_main_\_.py*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042905/what-is-main-py). If you'd like to have a callable script *main.py*, don't put it in you package. Besides http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169750/python3-submodules-setup-does-not-update-paths-when-run-with-m-switch might give you an answer to the new Error.

Comment: Ah sorry for that, I had very unstable Internet and the SO page told me there was an error while posting the comments, but in fact they did get posted. I am sorry for posting multiple times. And then I couldn't even delete any comment anymore, because my connection was soooo bad -.- And thanks for further advice!