# Env. Variables not set while running Minimal Flask application

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to follow the flask documentation on my windows machine given at the following link:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#debug-mode

Firstly I wrote the code below in a python script:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I saved this in a file called `run.py`

Then wrote this command in the command window:

```
set FLASK_APP = run.py 
flask run
```

Upon running this, I am getting the following error:

`"Error: Could not locate flask application. You did not provide the FLASK_APP environment variable"`

I was expecting to get this instead:

```
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

Can somebody tell me how to fix this?

Comment: That is the exact example provided in the Flask documentation. If it is not working, it is likely a bug in Flask itself. Contact the author.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I managed to fix the error by writing <python -m run.py> in cmd to run the file instead of <python run.py>. By doing this, I am now getting another error that says "Error while finding spec for 'run.py' << class AttributeError'>: module 'run' has no attribute '-path-'>". Can you please offer some help?

Comment: see [Python3 submodules setup does not update paths when run with -m switch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169750/), and note the comment about "*the -m switch takes a python identifier, not a filename*".

Comment: I got lost with the second link, but as of the first link to Flask Documentation that you had provided earlier, I ran exactly what has been mentioned `export FLASK_APP = run.py`  `flask run`, but am getting the following error "Could not locate flask application. You did not provide the FLASK_app evironment variable".   Will you be able to guide on this?

Comment: Sorry, this is as far as I can go.  I don't use Python.

Comment: "set FLASK_APP = run.py" should be "set FLASK_APP=run.py" (no space to the left and right of the equality sign)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I faced the same issue while using PowerShell and that fix worked for me:
instead of using `set FLASK_APP = run.py`, try `$env:FLASK_APP = "run.py"`

Comment: This solution works for my case when using PowerShell. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Experienced exact same problem (used Powershell instead of cmd) as the question starter and this solution works perfectly.

Comment: Could someone tell me how do I save this so I don't need to type it in each time I want to run my Flask application when I shut down my computer?

Comment: @CoreyLevinson There are some tips in the flask documentation: [Environment Variables From dotenv](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/cli/#environment-variables-from-dotenv), [Environment Variables From virtualenv](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/cli/#environment-variables-from-virtualenv)

Comment: I know it's old but worked for me. I'm using Visual Studio Code x64 on Windows 10, running powershell in the terminal.

Comment: YES! Works for me on Windows 8.1 using Powershell-as-admin inside Cmder. I LOVE it when someone posts a simple, precise solution to my problem :) thank you!

Comment: I have students on Windows running Command Prompt (not PowerShell) and this worked for them (two separate lines, leave out the brackets and numbers):
 [ 1 ] set FLASK_APP=run   [ 2 ] flask run

Comment: "set FLASK_APP = run.py" should be "set FLASK_APP=run.py" (no space to the left and right of the equality sign)

Answer (score 19):

If you are using powershell it does not works i dont know why
please use `cmd.exe`
since i use VScode editor it provide powershell as a terminal(`ctrl + back-tick`) by default so i was trying to run flask app on the powershell and it was giving me same response as you are getting

1. open cmd.exe (or if you are **VSCode** user like me simply write `cmd` on that terminal, or you can also press `Ctrl + Shift + C` to open a windowed cmd terminal)
2. `set FLASK_APP=hello.py` (without spaces, only for first run then it remember until restart of cmd)
3. `flask run` (or just flask will also work)

note: **this is only for windows user**

Answer (score 9):

1. `export FLASK_APP=run.py`
2. `flask run --host=0.0.0.0`

then can run normally, output something like:

```
 * Serving Flask app "hello"
 * Forcing debug mode on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 353-795-063
```

Answer (score 8):

I wonder why this is missing from the answer.

Here is a simple solution:

add app.run(port=5000)

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

app.run(port=5000)
```

and then in the same directory run the command

```
python run.app
```

Answer (score 4):

Different shell programs have **different ways to set the environment variable** in it. So that Flask can discover you application correctly.

- **Unix Bash/Zsh (Linux, Mac, etc.):**

  ```sh
  $ export FLASK_APP=hello
  $ flask run
  ```
- **Windows CMD:**

  ```
  > set FLASK_APP=hello
  > flask run
  ```
- **Windows PowerShell:**

  ```bsh
  > $env:FLASK_APP = "hello"
  > flask run
  ```

You can find more infomation in the [Flask docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/#application-discovery).

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the FLASK_APP variable outside of the virtual environment. I'm assuming the reason that it worked after @Fang restarted the command window is because that action automatically exited the virtual environment.

So, if you're in the virtual environment (indicated by a `(venv)` at the start of line on command window), then type the following commands:

```
deactivate

set FLASK_APP=run.py

venv\scripts\activate

flask run
```

Answer (score 3):

Just drop the space around '=' !

After half an hour searching for solution, I finally get what does 'You did not provide the FLASK_APP environment variable' mean. Because what I set is 'FLASK_APP ' variable (with space).

Comment: This describes and fixes exactly OP's problem and should IMHO be the selected answer. Running powershell to run a python script is overkill...

Answer (score 2):

Did you run your terminal as administrator?  I had the same problem, and running cmd/PowerShell as admin fixed it for me.

Edit:  I spoke too soon.  Running as admin did nothing.

The real answer (to my problem, at least) is a combination of some of the other answers.

1. Instead of using `set FLASK_APP = myApp.py`, use `setx FLASK_APP myApp.py`
2. Restart the terminal, and FLASK_APP will have the new value

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem, but the following command worked for me in PowerShell:

```
python -m flask run
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. Try setting the Command-Line variable like this :

```
setx FLASK_APP run.py
```

And then run it : `flask run`.

Answer (score 1):

Success with `setx FLASK_APP test.py` . Note: if not run, close command line and start other one.

```
D:\projects\flask-oauthlibpy2>.evn\Scripts\activate

(.evn) D:\projects\flask-oauthlibpy2>setx FLASK_APP test.py

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

(.evn) D:\projects\flask-oauthlibpy2>flask run
 * Serving Flask app "flask-oauthlibpy2.test"
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [24/May/2017 14:35:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Answer (score 1):

Just drop the space around equal to sign.
set FLASK_APP=python_file_name.py

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on windows and found a solution from the flask documentation: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/factory/

My file structure:
Flask_folder>>app

(NB! app folder contains: __init_.py and routes.py)

`> set FLASK_APP=app`

`> set FLASK_ENV=development`

`> flask run`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same problem by closing the command window and restart it.

Answer (score 0):

had a similar problem. got resolved by using the following:
flask run --no-reload

learnt this from flask documentation http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/server/

Answer (score 0):

I had got the same issue while running the first hello world for flask.

Ideally there should not be any space between 
so use 
set FLASK_APP=run.py

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

- Step 1: Open your CMD Command prompt
- Step 2: Go on the same directory in which my python file was on.
- Step 3: in the CMD command prompt run the command `setx FLASK_APP sqlAlchemy.py`
- Step 4: close terminal
- Step 5: In the CMD command prompt run the command `python - m flask run`

I have an Alienware laptop and am using Windows 10.

Not sure it worked but it was a combination of trial and ever. 
Depending on the OS you have the solution will vary it seems. 
IT could be an environmental variable issue but again not sure.

-
Here are other possible solutions that didn't work for me but I gathered them up as possibilities.

- OPTION 2
- set FLASK_APP=sqlalchemy.py

  - flask run
- OPTION 3
- set FLASK_APP=app
- set FLASK_ENV=development

  - flask run
    Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    > set FLASK_APP=Your_file_name.py
    > set FLASK_ENV=development
    > flask run
```

it must be work for windows user only

Answer (score 0):

You should leave a space between the equal sign and the file name like this in PowerShell in Windows.

> set FLASK_APP= market.py

this worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I was having this same problem running the commands as stated in Flask quick start. using Powershell on windows 10

```
projects>set export FLASK_APP=hello.py
projects>flask run
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

I needed to type `python <filename.py>` while being in the directory containing the file with
    from flask import Flask
    app = Flask(**name**)

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!
```

after that you will get a message with an IP address in it

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

you copy IP address into your browser and your to that point you should see your hello world statement then.