# How can I open a testing server for flask?

Tags: python, flask, server, terminal, project

I am creating a blog using Flask. However, when trying to run my code on a local server, I am unable to do so, as it comes with this error:
[Error: Failed to find Flask application or factory in module "flaskblog". Use "FLASK_APP=flaskblog:name to specify one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRFJc.png)

I had typed in, "set FLASK_APP=flaskblog.py" in my terminal prior, then typed in "flask run." What would be the next best steps to take so I can run the code on a local server? Running this on a Windows 10 computer.

Comment: If by chance you're using PowerShell the syntax for the environment variable will be different: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40852895/42346

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a bash cli, try using "export FLASK_APP=flaskblog.py". Set might only work if you are using something like Windows CMD.

Comment: I am using Windows CMD actually.

Comment: Within CMD, when you type "echo %FLASK_APP%", does it output "flaskblog.py"?