# 'flask run' is running a file in another folder

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables

so I have a /app/app.py folder and another /todo/todo.py folder.
I was working on the app.py testing with flask, but now I want to run the todo.py file.
I navigated to todo/todo.py and set the environment variable to 'set FLASK_APP=todo.py', but whenever I run 'flask run' command the browser keeps rendering the content of app.py.
How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using

```
set FLASK_APP = todo.py
```

try

```
$env:FLASK_APP = "todo.py"
```

source: [Env. Variables not set while running Minimal Flask application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37826016/env-variables-not-set-while-running-minimal-flask-application/40852895#40852895)